# Non-greedy regular expression match for multicharacter delimiters in awk

Tags: regex, awk

Consider the string `"AB 1 BA 2 AB 3 BA"`. How can I match the content between `"AB"` and `"BA"` in a non-greedy fashion (in awk)?

I have tried the following:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    str="AB 1 BA 2 AB 3 BA"
    regex="AB([^B][^A]|B[^A]|[^B]A)*BA"
    if (match(str,regex))
        print substr(str,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}'
```

with no output. I believe the reason for no match is that there is an odd number of characters between `"AB"` and `"BA"`. If I replace `str` with `"AB 11 BA 22 AB 33 BA"` the regex seems to work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merge your two negated character classes and remove the `[^A]` from the second alternation:

```
regex = "AB([^AB]|B|[^B]A)*BA"
```

This regex fails on the string `ABABA`, though - not sure if that is a problem.

**Explanation:**

```
AB       # Match AB
(        # Group 1 (could also be non-capturing)
 [^AB]   # Match any character except A or B
|        # or
 B       # Match B
|        # or
 [^B]A   # Match any character except B, then A
)*       # Repeat as needed
BA       # Match BA
```

Since the only way to match an `A` in the alternation is by matching a character except `B` before it, we can safely use the simple `B` as one of the alternatives.

Comment: Still a little bit confused :) Why does `AB([^AB]|[^B]A)*BA` match `ABBBA` whereas it does not match `ABABA`?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: That regex doesn't match `ABBBA`...mine does because there is a `B` in the alternation.

Comment: I was wondering why your regex is different from the one I derive from the DFA. Turn out that it is under-matching. By the way, the correct one is `AB([^B]|B+[^AB])*B*BA`.

Comment: would `AB(B+[^A]|[^B]+)*B+A` be faster ?

Answer (score 5):

The other answer didn't really answer: how to match non-greedily? 
Looks like it can't be done in (G)AWK. The manual says this:

> awk (and POSIX) regular expressions always match the leftmost, longest
>   sequence of input characters that can match.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Leftmost-Longest

And the whole manual doesn't contain the words "greedy" nor "lazy". It mentions Extended Regular Expressions, but [for greedy matching you'd need Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454172/non-greedy-matching-with-grep). So… no, can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

For general expressions, I'm using this as a non-greedy match:

```
function smatch(s, r) {
    if (match(s, r)) {
        m = RSTART
        do {
            n = RLENGTH
        } while (match(substr(s, m, n - 1), r))
        RSTART = m
        RLENGTH = n
        return RSTART
    } else return 0
}
```

`smatch` behaves like `match`, returning:

> the  position  in  `s`  where  the  regular expression `r` occurs, or 0 if it does not. The variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` are set to the position and length of the matched string.

Answer (score 1):

Mark the field with special text (backspace or \x00 or similar), then include the field splitter in the gsub command to remove the extra field splitter.

```
$1="\b";
gsub("\b"FS,"")
```