# Replace random text between a constant starting and ending string using shell command

Tags: shell, sed, awk

How to replace random text between `:50K` and `:53B` in each line with `CREDIT` using shell?

The input is

```
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50K:xxxxhh:53B:fg :43:fg $
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50K:yyyyhh:53B:fg :43:fg $
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50K:zzzzz:53B:fg :43:fg $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 sed 's/:50K.*:53B/:50KCREDIT:53B/g'
```

A basic sed replace expression:

`s/what_to_look_for/what_to_replace_with/`

`g` means "do it for all found patterns on the line" (you might want to skip that).

**Usage:**
You use sed by either letting it read from stdin:

```
 cat path/to/your_text_file | sed 's/:50K.*:53B/:50KCREDIT:53B/g'
```

or by suplying the text file in which you want to replace as an argument

```
 sed 's/:50K.*:53B/:50KCREDIT:53B/g' path/to/your_text_file
```

Each will print the replace version to stdout. Neither will modify the original file in place.

Comment: Getting following error:sed: command garbled: s/:50K.*53B/:50KCREDIT53B/g
sh: MT.txt^M: not found
sh: ^M: execute permission denied

Comment: You have to cat your text file into it, or do it like:
sed 's/:50K.*:53B/:50KCREDIT:53B/g' path/to/your_text_file

Comment: Glad it helped. Note: `.*` also matches empty strings (zero or more of anything). If there must be something in between your prefix and postfix, change it to `..*`, which is sed's way of saying .+ like in the perl expression bellow (the perl solution is really better, as it allows more customization more easily).

Comment: This solution won't work if the random text contains also the string ":53B"
How would you fix your solution in this case?

Comment: @hongo I wouldn't. Regexes tend to be greedy, so it just works. Try `sed 's/:50K.*:53B/:50KCREDIT:53B/g' <<<':50Kfoobar:53B:53B:53Bbaz:53B:53B'`

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F":50K|:53B" '{$2=":50KCREDIT:53B"}8' OFS="" file
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50KCREDIT:53B:fg :43:fg $
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50KCREDIT:53B:fg :43:fg $
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50KCREDIT:53B:fg :43:fg $
```

```
awk '{sub(/:50K.*:53B/,":50KCREDIT:53B")}8' file
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50KCREDIT:53B:fg :43:fg $
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50KCREDIT:53B:fg :43:fg $
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50KCREDIT:53B:fg :43:fg $
```

`gnuawk`

```
awk '{print gensub(/(:50K).*(:53B)/,"\\1CREDIT\\2","g")}' file
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50KCREDIT:53B:fg :43:fg $
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50KCREDIT:53B:fg :43:fg $
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50KCREDIT:53B:fg :43:fg $
```

Comment: The last two approaches are greedy. I do not think it is of any importance here, but it might be nice to mention..

Comment: @HåkonHægland  Hei, how do I make them non greed.  I tried to change `.*` with `[^:]+` but this does not work.

Comment: I think it is difficult to make it nongreedy, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783959/non-greedy-regular-expression-match-for-multicharacter-delimiters-in-awk . It is better to use perl nongreedy quantifier .*?, see answer of @mgsk .

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/(\:50K).+?(\:53B)/${1}CREDIT${2}/g;' input_file
```

Basic usage:

```
s/replace_this/with_this/g;
```

`(\:50K)` and `(\:53B)` in `replace this` part are in parenthesis because these are so called capturing groups. You can refer to these capturing groups as `${1}` and `${2}` (or `\1` and `\2`) in the `with_this` part, `CREDIT` as literal replacing whatever is in between ( `.+?(\:53B)` - means whatever character, whatever number of occurrences until :53B appears).

`:` is escaped because it's a metacharacter in regex.

Backup of the file will be saved to input_file.bak

Using your input, the output is:

```
$ cat input_file
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50KCREDIT:53B:fg :43:fg $
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50KCREDIT:53B:fg :43:fg $
{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50KCREDIT:53B:fg :43:fg $
```

Hope it helps.